# NgRx compound selector

Tags: typescript, ngrx

Is there a way to create a compound selector in NgRx?

Example:

```
export const paramSelector = (id) => createSelector(
  someState,
  state => state[id]
);

export const selectedId = createSelector(
  someOtherState,
  state => state.id
);

export const compoundSelector = createSelector(
  selectedId,
  id => paramSelector(id),
  state => state
);
```

Obviously above code doesn't work. Is there any way to get the desired result (last snipped)?

---

The idea is to have specialized parametrized selectors, and some higher level selectors consuming them. Imagine `paramSelector` is more complex. Sometimes you want to use `paramSelector` with specific parameters. Sometimes you don't want to provide params yourself, you want to get it somewhere from the store (eg. router state).

Now, you never want to repeat the same code, thus need for a compound selector.

---

#### Edit

Feature request was created. It can be found [here](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1226).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @RenéWinkler I have updated question. I hope now it is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your first snippet should work, the second wont - for more info I refer you to [NgRx: Parameterized selectors](https://medium.com/@timdeschryver/ngrx-parameterized-selector-e3f610529f8).

For example:

```
export const selectCustomer = (id: string) => createSelector(
  getCustomers,
  customers => customers[id]
);
```

In one of the next releases it will be possible to add extra props to your selectors, as in:

```
export const getCustomerById = createSelector(
  getCustomers,
  (customers, props) => customers[props.id]
)
```

Comment: Hello, I don't think it answers the question. Seeing the confusion, I have updated my example. Hope now it is more clear.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following then. Do you mean if there is a way to have props to your selectors as in reselect? https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#accessing-react-props-in-selectors

Comment: Ok, what I am trying to do is pretty simple I want to get param for selector from a different selector. In `compoundSelector` the first line is providing selector. In the second line, it projects first selector and returns selector. In the third line, it projects the final state. In your example, you use the word "props" very extensively, and I have to admit I have not come across this word until now. I did a little search and there was nothing. Nothing in ng-conf dedicated to NgRx, nor in NgRx documentation. Could you explain what does this word mean?

Comment: With props I mean that it's possible that selectors receive an extra argument 'properties', this can be anything you like. Allowing you to do the example in the answer or something like:
const selector = createSelector(
  state => state.count * 10,
  (state, props) => state.count + props.value,
  (one, two) => one + two
);
 The reason you never heard of it is because it's in development.

Comment: It isn't possible to access the `id` property in your compoundSelector example

Comment: Perhaps this is a good time to make a feature request. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Bielik did you post a FR at ngrx? Searching for a solution to the same problem here.

Comment: @GiacomoVoß Yes, sorry I didn't post it earlier. You can find it in here https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1226